# Как сгруппировать строки по неделям, месяцам и кварталам?

Tags: java

Получаю несколько да в String формате . И мне нужно их сгруппировать по неделям, месяцам и кварталам . Как это реализовать на java?

Пробовал таким способом

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main  {
    private Map<Integer, List<String>> dates;
    private String Date;


   

     public void DataPick() {
    
            dates = new HashMap<>();
    
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-01");
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-01");
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-05");
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-10");
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-12");
            putDataInCollection("2017-01-15");
    
        }

    @Test
        public void putDataInCollection(String order){
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime((java.util.Date) getDate(order));
    
    
            List<String> datesList ;
            if (dates.get(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR))!=null) {
                datesList = dates.get(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
            } else {
                datesList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            datesList.add(order);
    
            dates.put(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR),datesList);
        System.out.println(dates);
        }
   

     @Test
        public Comparable<java.util.Date> getDate(String order) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            try {
                convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(Date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(convertedDate);
            return convertedDate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А при чём тут javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Main {
    
    private final static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-10", "2017-03-12", "2017-01-15");
        Map<Integer, List<LocalDate>> groupingByMonth = collect(dates, LocalDate::getMonthValue);
        Map<Integer, List<LocalDate>> groupingByQuarter = collect(dates, date->date->(date.getMonthValue()-1)/3);
                
    }

    public static Map<Integer, List<LocalDate>> collect(Iterable<String> dates, Function<LocalDate, Integer> collector) {        
        return StreamSupport.stream(dates.spliterator(), false)
                .map(date -> LocalDate.parse(date, FORMATTER))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(collector));
    }
    
}
```

Здесь мы получаем результат, сгруппированный по месяцам и кварталам. По неделям допишите сами способом, аналогичным с кварталами, т.е. измените вот эту функцию для подсчета недель : date->(date.getMonthValue()-1)/3

в целом это не сложно, просто вы не сказали, как именно вы хотите считать недели? Если год начинается в среду, то первая неделя это со среды по воскресенье (а может по субботу) или это все же первые 7 дней года?

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. По неделям группировка в зависимости от того на какой день недели выпадает 1 января . Если среда то ( с среды по воскресенье ) это первая неделя и так далее

Comment: Группировка месяцев по кварталам получается такая: `{1={1, 2, 3}, 2={4, 5, 6, 7}, 3={8, 9, 10, 11}, 4={12}}`

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с датами *уже почти 9 лет* рекомендуется использовать Java Date/Time API и соответствующие классы `LocalDate` вместо `java.util.Date` и особенно `Calendar` / `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Так как требуется получить группировку по разным ключам, то можно написать общий метод, который принимает на вход список дат и некую функцию для вычисления ключа (месяц, квартал, неделя).

Реализация с использованием Stream API:

```java
private static Map<Integer, List<String>> groupDatesBy(List<String> dates, Function<String, Integer> keyMapper) {
    return dates.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyMapper));
}
```

Вариант без стримов с использованием `Map::computeIfAbsent`:

```java
private static Map<Integer, List<String>> groupDatesBy(List<String> dates, Function<String, Integer> keyMapper) {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (String date : dates) {
        result.computeIfAbsent(keyMapper.apply(date), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(date);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

---

Группировка по месяцам тривиальна, функция получения месяца из строковой даты выглядит как `d -> LocalDate.parse(d).getMonthValue()`:

```java
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> datesByMonth(List<String> dates) {
    return groupDatesBy(dates, d -> LocalDate.parse(d).getMonthValue());
}
```

Аналогично, номер квартала следует *правильно* вычислить по номеру месяца следующим образом `d -> (LocalDate.parse(d).getMonthValue() - 1) / 3 + 1` (делить следует на количество месяцев в квартале, а не на количество кварталов в году):

```java
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> datesByQuarter(List<String> dates) {
    return groupDatesBy(dates, d -> (LocalDate.parse(d).getMonthValue() - 1) / 3 + 1);
}
```

А вот группировку по номеру недели можно получить при помощи класса [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html), в котором определяется первый день недели и минимальное количество дней в первой неделе года (если меньше минимума, будет считаться как 52 неделя прошлого года для метода [`WeekFields::weekOfWeekBasedYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfWeekBasedYear--) или 0 для [`WeekFields::weekOfYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfYear--) ).

```java
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> datesByWeek(WeekFields weekFields, List<String> dates) {
    return groupDatesBy(dates, d -> LocalDate.parse(d).get(weekFields.weekOfYear()));
}
```

---

Тесты:

```java
var byMonth = datesByMonth(Arrays.asList("2017-01-02", "2017-01-31", "2017-02-18", "2017-03-30"));
System.out.println("Month: " + byMonth);

var byQuarter = datesByQuarter(Arrays.asList("2017-01-02", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-18", "2017-06-30", "2017-07-25", "2017-08-31", "2017-09-25", "2017-11-03", "2017-12-31"));
System.out.println("Quart: " + byQuarter);

var dates = Arrays.asList("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-10", "2017-01-12", "2017-01-15", "2017-01-17");

var weekFields = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 1);// WeekFields.SUNDAY_START;
var byWeekSun = datesByWeek(weekFields, dates);

System.out.println("SUN: " + byWeekSun);

var byWeekIso = datesByWeek(WeekFields.ISO, dates);
System.out.println("ISO: " + byWeekIso);
```

Результаты:

```
Month: {1=[2017-01-02, 2017-01-31], 2=[2017-02-18], 3=[2017-03-30]}
Quart: {1=[2017-01-02, 2017-03-31], 2=[2017-04-18, 2017-06-30], 3=[2017-07-25, 2017-08-31, 2017-09-25], 4=[2017-11-03, 2017-12-31]}
SUN: {1=[2017-01-01, 2017-01-01, 2017-01-05], 2=[2017-01-10, 2017-01-12], 3=[2017-01-15, 2017-01-17]}
ISO: {0=[2017-01-01, 2017-01-01], 1=[2017-01-05], 2=[2017-01-10, 2017-01-12, 2017-01-15], 3=[2017-01-17]}
```