# Из года создать недели в map

Tags: java

Есть такие даты

```
[
    {
    "name" : "2022-07-20",
    "percentY" : "64.8 ",
    "main" : 842,
    "y" : 546,
    "z" : 0
  }, 
{
    "name" : "2022-07-25",
    "percentY" : "0.0 ",
    "main" : 1354,
    "y" : 0,
    "z" : 0
  }, {
    "name" : "2022-07-26",
    "percentY" : "0.0 ",
    "main" : 30,
    "y" : 0,
    "z" : 0
  }]
```

Нужно эти даты сгруппировать по неделям.
так начинается с июля то и неделя там 29. Таким образом , чтоб все даты которые входит в 29 неделю выводились так:
{29 - 2 } . Значит что, в 29 неделе 2 даты . И так для всех остальных дат

Comment: Начните тут https://www.baeldung.com/java-get-week-number

Answer (score 0):

Для группировки по номеру недели следует использовать класс [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) из Java Date/Time API (см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1494983/386633) на похожий вопрос: [Как сгруппировать строки по неделям, месяцам и кварталам?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493884/)).

Однако здесь следует точно определить, как именно будет вычисляться номер недели, так как это зависит от дня начала недели -- два самых известных подхода воскресенье или понедельник, и минимального количества дней, которые должны быть в неделе.

> *Если дней в первой неделе меньше минимума, то она будет считаться как 52 неделя прошлого года для метода `WeekFields::weekOfWeekBasedYear` или 0 для `WeekFields::weekOfYear`.*

Таким образом, для выполнения группировки можно определить метод вроде такого, чтобы можно было передать ссылку на любой из вышеуказанных методов:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> datesByWeek(Supplier<TemporalField> weekField, List<String> dates) {
    return dates.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            d -> LocalDate.parse(d).get(weekField.get()),
            LinkedHashMap::new, // поддержать порядок вставки
            Collectors.summingInt(d -> 1)
    ));
}
```

Тест для разных экземпляров `WeekFields` c первым и последним днём года:

```java
var dates = Arrays.asList("2022-01-01", "2022-07-20", "2022-07-25", "2022-07-26", "2022-12-31");        
Supplier<TemporalField> weekFields = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 1)::weekOfWeekBasedYear;
var byWeekMon = datesByWeek(weekFields, dates);

System.out.println("MON: " + byWeekMon);

var byWeekSun = datesByWeek(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START::weekOfYear, dates);
System.out.println("SUN: " + byWeekSun);        

var byWeekIso = datesByWeek(WeekFields.ISO::weekOfYear, dates);
System.out.println("ISO: " + byWeekIso);
```

Результаты:

```
MON: {1=2, 30=1, 31=2}        // номер недели 1 для начала и конца года
SUN: {1=1, 30=1, 31=2, 53=1}
ISO: {0=1, 29=1, 30=2, 52=1}
```

Кстати, ни по одному календарю не выходит, что 25 и 26 июля 2022 года пришлись на 29 неделю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что не по ISO и ГОСТУ считается.
Если следовать правилу, то первой неделей года является та неделя, на которую попадает первый четверг нового года, или, что эквивалентно, та неделя, которая содержит число 4 января.
Должно быть `WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 4)`

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov, не совсем понял, к чему относится ваш комментарий